# Negativity of a power function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

For what values (or intervals) of 'a' it holds $2(x+1)^a$ - $x^a$ - $(x+2)^a$$<0$, where $x\in N$.

I tried to do it by first derivative test but it again gives almost same type expression which is difficult to solve.

By Jensen's inequality it is OK but then I am unable to show that for what values of 'a' the given function $2(x+1)^a$ - $x^a$ - $(x+2)^a$ is convex.

For $a=\frac{-1}{2}$ it holds.

Answer (score 1):

We can start by simplifying the expression $2(x+1)^a - x^a - (x+1)^a < 0$ to $(x+1)^a < x^a$. Since $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $x^a > 0$, we can reduce that to $(\frac{x+1}{x})^a < 1$.

Simply take the $\log$ of both sides to get $a < 0$.

Comment: thank you for your reply but sorry I edited the question now need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can see

$ 2(x+1)^a - x^a - (x+2)^a < 0 \iff (x+1)^a - x^a < (x+2)^a - (x+1)^a $

Thus, it's not about negativity. It's about the speed of increasing of power function.